# How can I create an OAuth2 secured REST API using Spring?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have followed a bunch of guides to no avail.
I think I have a pretty simple case so here goes:

I want to create a REST API using Spring (Boot). I have a user database which I access using Spring Data and I have already prepared a `UserDetailsService` for it.

Now I want to add OAuth2 security using the implicit flow, however I have not been able to get this to work. I do not wish to separate the Authorization server and the Resource server since the key is to keep deployment simple.

How would you go about this?